# Select all rows from joined with multiple conditions tables with null values

Tags: sql, join, multiple-conditions

I want to join two tables, Sales and Budget.

Sales table columns:

```
| Customer | Period | Sales |
```

Budget table columns:

```
| Customer | Period | SaleBudget |
```

Sales table has data for periods 1, 2, and 3. Budget has data for periods 1-12. When I try to run below query I get only data for periods from Sales table matched with Budget table. But my goal is to get all data from both tables. Could you give me a hint how to change query?

```
Select s.Customer, b.SaleBudget, s.Sales from Sales s
full outer join Budget b on b.Customer = s.Customer and b.Period = s.Period
```

Comment: Your query as posted should do exactly what you desire - with the exception of not correctly supporting NULL values for the unmatched rows. Seems odd that you omit the Period column from that list since you need to know both customer and period to make sense of the budget and sales numbers. Why do you think it does not "work"?

Comment: There is more columns in these tables but it has no impact on query result. I test it with minimum columns to symplify. Unfortunately I have no idea what to do next. Null values from table Sales are missing in the query result.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you use left join its join the rows that are same in

```
b.Customer = s.Customer and b.Period = s.Period
```

if you want have all of the rows you shouldn't use left join;
The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matching records from the right table (table2);
there is not any way that get some data matching and some data Inconsistency in one shape.

Comment: Ok, should I use union all or is there some easier way?

Comment: In Union All your tables should have same type of column for example => "SELECT Id,FirstName FROM City Union All SELECT Id,FirstName From City_2"; Then Union All is not use this;

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: There is one solution but it's not good work; you have two tables Sales And Budgets that they should match with Customer And Period; you can show rows that have matched clearly but another rows shows with some null values in for example Sales columns;this is not regular but you can do it